# Office UI Fabric Classes Missing in Sharepoint Framework Project

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, sharepointframework

I'm new to Sharepoint Framework but I used the 'yo @microsoft/sharepoint' command to create a new React/SPFx project.  However, in doing so it seems that I don't have access to **some** of the CSS classes available in OfficeUI Fabric.  For example if I try to create a typical grid layout, the ms-Grid-row and ms-Grid-col classes work as expected but the sizing utility classes do not (ms-sm6, ms-lg6). Other fabric classes work as well such as ms-bgColor-neutralLight, ms-font-xl, and ms-fontWeight-semibold ... so a portion of that styling is coming through.

If I add a link reference to the workbench.html file pointing to the CDN of fabric.css I get those classes working again....but that is not a solution since that file is just a temporary file build for testing at compile time.

Is there something else that needs to be done to include fabric.css (or fabric.min.css) in my project?

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue. Yeoman generated SPFX webpart (React) for an on premises instance. Digging into the node module, I found the classes didn't match the documentation. Where the documentation would say to use **ms-md6**, the css file has **ms-u-md6**. Seems like all of the layout classes follow this pattern of ms-u- rather than just ms-... Adding the -u to the className is now giving me appropriately sized columns.

The path to the file I found the classes in is: .../node_modules/office-ui-fabric/dist/css/fabric.css (YMMV)